# New to Micro-controllers and Lower level programming, Is this possible to do?

Tags: android, open-source, labview

Hey All I'm a recently graduated BS in Mechanical Engineering and am working on a project that is getting into to the field of CS and I am looking to remake a treadmill after its 1990's motherboard finally quit.

I have the following assets:

- Treadmill with broken motherboard (all other components tested and functional)
- Touch screen monitor similar to [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824016406)
- A polar heart rate monitor.
- Multiple hard drives, joysticks and other USB accessories.
- NI LabVIEW full subscription suite
- 2 functioning (2000's era) laptops with no OS.
- Solidworks
- Local maker's space

I have a few main goals and stretch goals and I'd like some advice as to which should be easy enough to implement and which will take me [a research team and 5 years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjxPE.png)

## This should be easy... right?

1. Get a PID controller setup with a micro controller to spin treadmill belt at [n]mph and adjust incline to [n2] degrees based on a hardware dial, knob, or push button physical input

   ```
   * get microcontroller to read motor encoders for speed/incline 

   * get microcontroller to recognize input from a physical button

   * get microcontroller to compare current speed/incline values with target values 
     and increase/decrease current to motors appropriately 

   * have microcontroller display info on LCD screen
   ```
2. Change from physical input to touchscreen input.

   `*Figure out what they're doing`[in link 1 in comments below]`and adjust for what I currently have (or buy fresh if absolutely necessary)`

   ```
   * change input from hardware buttons to software <up> <down> arrows

   * Add hardware E-stop
   ```

It looks like there are plenty of libraries and devices online that are doing elements of these two steps, combining them may be difficult due to my inexperience, but not hard for the hardware and software.

## Medium Difficulty (I saw a guy do this once)

3. Upload some kind of Linux distribution or other OS onto my microcontroller and turn my program into an application.

   ```
   *Learn how to install Linux/Other OS

   *Compile program as application

   *Section off the bottom of the LCD Screen as a treadmill specific taskbar

   * (bonus round) Make treadmill specific taskbar able to be moved and snapped 
     (similar to the windows taskbar)
   ```
4. Add feedback from a heart rate monitor to the treadmill for heart rate PID control

   ```
   *SparkFun has a Single Lead Heart Rate Monitor - AD8232 [Link 2] write an application 
    to read the monitor and control the treadmill program accordingly.
   ```

I feel like this is theoretically possible but I don't really know how I would go about it. I also see how either of these tasks could be infinitely more complex than I'm thinking it will be.

## Hard mode (Is this even possible?)

5. Put on smartphone style functionality.

   ```
   * Install Android OS onto microcontroller

   * Install Google Play store

   * dedicate a set of pixels to the "treadmill OS" and the rest to the  "smartphone."

   * Add some sort of hook for the "treadmill OS" into the Android OS and maybe write
   a few apps to control the treadmill based on [arbitrary value in app]
   ```

If I can do this, why are all the super expensive and advanced treadmills on the market so crappy in terms of their software?

---

For my skill set I'm pretty good on how to physically put everything together (but will need to make few post to the Electronics stack exchange as to how to get a something the size of a smartphone to regulate 120V 60hz power correctly)

**My main question** is how much of this is actually conceivable to do and if I am to do it in a way that satisfies all my desires, should I:

A) look to by a particular type of microcontroller to do all of this(reccomendations would be appreciated)

B) Start with one of my two Laptops and write an interface for a microcontroller that just does the easy stuff

C) Install the Android OS on one of my laptops and begin write a [treadmill app]

D) Do something I haven't thought of because this is not my field.

*ps: Although this is a DIY project, when it comes to the coding, I really don't want to be reinventing the wheel so please let me know about any libraries or resources that may exist which could be helpful*

Comment: [link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSKmG1VFA4w) 
and
[link 2](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12650)

Comment: I appreciate your problem & the effort you've put into formulating this question but it is way too broad of a question for this site.  I can't bring myself to flag it for closure but don't be surprised if someone does.  I wish you luck and you may even get some info here that is of use.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for some help on what type of questions are appropriate for this site.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of afraid of that. I spent last night figuring out how to reduce the scope of the problem without making it an X Y but my base problem isn't as much of a *How to [task]* but a *What to [task]* If you can advise me on a general way to start or how to reduce my question I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a project!

## Getting the treadmill working

If your goal is to "get the treadmill working," then don't bother with any of this; instead focus on debugging the motherboard. There's probably just 1 component that went bad, and it will be easier and faster to fix that than to build everything you mentioned up through easy/medium/hard modes. But I know your goal is learning and fun, not simply to get it working :)

## Control loops and data collection

As you've already identified, you need something for low-level access to the hardware (controlling the treadmill and reading heart rate back). This type of work is perfect for a micro, so you're on the right path there. Android or Linux are needlessly complex for these tasks, and implementing them will be a lot more work for you, with not much advantage.

## User interaction

At a bare minimum, the existing physical buttons and knobs will directly control the micro. Once you hit that checkpoint, congratulations, your treadmill works again.

But you don't want "working", you want "cool". You mentioned a few different ways for users to interact with your system: displays, touch screens, phones, etc. Already this is going to be a huge project, so don't waste time reinventing the wheel by trying to manually implement those things. Find a working system (your laptop, daily cellphone, or even a cheap tablet online), and use that to talk with your low-level micro over something like Bluetooth or WiFi.

## Choosing the right tools

If you pick something obscure, expect to spend tons of time simply trying to get basic functionality out of it. So in general, you want to pick hardware & software that:

- is robust (many people use it with minimal issue)
- has a large community (for support from other experts/hobbyists)
- has a large ecosystem (with lots of libraries that you can leverage)

The Arduino might be a good micro for you. Look into that.

For the "cool" display, your personal phone is probably the best option. The app development for your phone is robust and will have tons of support *when* you need it.

## Other thoughts

- You mentioned LabVIEW: stop doing that. It's the wrong tool for almost every goal you have.
- You asked how to regulate mains power down to a small board: buy/find any old wall-wart adapter from old electronics around your home. Cut off the tip. Connect the wires to your board. Done. (all the magic is inside the brick block).
- You asked which approach is best: B. Get the treadmill working with a basic micro. Then add wireless to the micro. Then write an app to give you a sweet display and control of the treadmill (via the micro).
- E-stop. Smart.

Comment: Great answer spoiled by silly comment about LabVIEW - this would be a perfectly good choice for implementing a dedicated UI using the laptop and touch screen, leaving the microcontroller to take care of the low-level stuff. In fact it could almost certainly be used for the low-level control too, via the third-party Arduino compiler and/or the ability to deploy real-time code to Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black targets using the LINX tool (for non-commercial applications), especially if the questioner already has LabVIEW experience.

Comment: Sorry that point ruined it for you, but it's the truth. Agreed, it would be great for a laptop UI talking to the uC, but the questioner is pretty clearly looking for a smartphone solution eventually. Try writing an Android app in LabVIEW... The questioner said he's fresh out of school and owns LabVIEW, but never suggested he knows how to use it. LabVIEW (especially for embedded) does not have the large ecosystem or community the questioner will absolutely need. Based on the question, his software background is pretty weak, which is an especially bad mix for LabVIEW.

Comment: I get the impression the questioner mentions Android because they think that's what they want it to look like, not because it's a hard requirement to run Android apps. Anyway they can read our opinions and make their own judgement.